# If all roots of $f$ generate a splitting field, is $f$ irreducible?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Recently I had to prove the existence of some irreducible polynomial. I wanted to use the following statement, but I do not know if it is true:

### The Statement:

Let $F$ be a field. If $f\in F[X]$ is such that for all roots $\alpha$ of $f$ $F[\alpha]$ is a splitting field for $f$, then $f$ is irreducible.

### My Question:

Is this true? Cyclotomic polynomials have this property and are irreducible. Would the answer change depending on the characteristic of the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it’s false. Consider $f(x)=(x^2-2)((x-1)^2-2)$ in characteristic not two.

Answer (score 1):

Look at $(X^2-2)^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ for a counterexample.